# Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor

Tags: typescript, oop, abstract-class

how i can solve this issue with typescript ?

ex: When you have a class registers, and when you want creates a instances of all classes registered ?

```
export abstract class FooAbstract {
    static registers: typeof FooAbstract[] = []; // a registers
    static create<T extends FooAbstract>(constr:  new ()=>T) {
        return new constr();
    }
}

export  class A extends FooAbstract {
   name:string;
}
FooAbstract.registers.push(A); // in my case i use decoration, but not matter !


// what should be the good way here ?
const test = FooAbstract.registers.map((cls)=> cls.create(cls))
```

[image]

```
Argument of type 'typeof FooAbstract' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => FooAbstract'.
  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.ts(2345)
```

Comment: why don't you create a generator function factory instead of a type-based? the effort is exactly the same, but there's no pain.

Comment: am new to typescript, did you have a ref of doc for this ?

Comment: Please do not edit the question to include your own answer to it - this is confusing for readers, and bypasses the voting mechanism which allows other users to signpost which answers are most helpful. If you have an answer to your own question, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: ho oki right, make sence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line `(constr: new () => T)` .
`create` static method expects a regular constructor, not an abstract constructr whereas you are trying to pass an abstract constructor to this method.
See here `FooAbstract.registers.map((cls) => cls.create(cls))`. `cls.create` expects `new () => T` but you are trying to use `abstract new () => T`.

You can add `abstract` flag/modifier to `constr` argument.

```js
export abstract class FooAbstract {
    static registers: typeof FooAbstract[] = [];
    static create<T extends FooAbstract>(constr: abstract new () => T) { // add `abstract` modifier
        return new constr();
    }
}


const test = FooAbstract.registers.map((cls) => cls.create(cls))
```

But above approach, causes a new problem. You are not allowed to create an instance of abstract class, `new constr() // <--- error is here`.

**UNSAFE APPROACH, MIGHT CAUSE AN ERROR IN RUNTIME. SEE @kaya3 COMMENTS**

If you want to create an instance of some class, this class should not be an `abstract`.

Hence, we need to create an empty anonymous class which will extends our abstract class:

```js
export abstract class FooAbstract {
    static registers: typeof FooAbstract[] = [];
    static create = <T extends FooAbstract>(constr: new () => T) => new constr()
}


const test = FooAbstract.registers.map((cls) =>
    cls.create(class extends cls { }) // <--- anonymous class is just a wrapper
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAMQggEFV0t4BvAWACg4W40EYBLTOKYAc05pgUFAC44MAJ5hgEAGYkylNBmwBtALpwAvHC0BuJqzYwO3OJj4dguuAB4AKnFAxgAOwAmRUhSpqYAD4ACkwId1UJd2AAdzhggEpdQLhHJJ0U6LiwiPREpgBfJmLGHLRJYHK9XxVqbAA6PkFhUXqAWwQwYNDcFHTA41Y8FHqrYBsegiJXD29LXrhaOAKkgHpVhwBabcR3cKk2iABXIjwpuCE4ACsT%20AQ4GIwwWSgmBKYgA)

There is another one solution. You can just remove `abstract` keyword from `FooAbstract` class definition.

**P.S.** I'm not an OOP expert, so I can't say whether the answer I have provided meets OOP good practices or not. I have shown you just how to fix TS error

**P.P.S** if using `abstract` class or even OOP approach is not important for you, I can recommend another approach if you will provide more details to your question.

Comment: This is not safe. You cannot just write `class extends cls {}` to make a concrete subclass of an arbitrary abstract class. If `cls` is abstract then you should expect it to be missing implementations of some methods in its interface. In that case your anonymous subclass is also missing those methods, so it is not safe to instantiate it. The real solution is to require that the classes in the registry aren't abstract in the first place.

Comment: hum you give me idea, what about ? `return new (constr as new ()=>T)();` 
it look fine , but it safe in ts ? it a good apraoche ?
`
 static create<T extends FooAbstract>(constr: abstract new ()=>T) {
    
  return new (constr as new ()=>T)();
 }
`

Comment: oki thanks all  for help, i edit my answer with the approach i retain. :)

Comment: @kaya3 see this tsplay.dev/Wkj7lm  . What makes you think that `anonymous subclass is also missing those methods`

Comment: yes it is not bad, however I am not at ease with it.
`cls.create (class extends cls {})` , wrapping like this , am not also sure about perf !

Comment: Just because the Typescript compiler doesn't give you an error doesn't mean it's necessarily safe. It's unsafe for the reason I've explained. Here's a demonstration. https://tsplay.dev/Wy5A2W

Comment: @kaya3 I got it, thanks. Made an update. Good point

Answer (score 1):

Each class in your registry must be `new`-able without any arguments. This means it should not be allowed to contain abstract classes, or classes whose constructors require arguments. You need to change the type of your registry to specify this. I've written a `NoArgsConstructor` helper type to simplify this.

```
type NoArgsConstructor<T> = new () => T

export abstract class FooAbstract {
    static registers: NoArgsConstructor<FooAbstract>[] = [];
    static create<T extends FooAbstract>(constr: NoArgsConstructor<T>): T {
        return new constr();
    }
}

export class A extends FooAbstract {
    name:string = 'foo';
}
FooAbstract.registers.push(A);

const test = FooAbstract.registers.map(cls => FooAbstract.create(cls));
```

Note also that the call to the static `create` method needs to be on `FooAbstract`, not on `cls`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gQQE4HMDOBhOA7NwkCuAxsHEgDwAqAfFALxTYQDuUAFAJT22UCwAUAIgAPMGWBQAhgCM8SSSShEANpLRooAMTiJZ+BRIDeAqKah5JwAJZEoSCCit4ISNAC5YiVJhxzipCm1dOQNqAG0AXXooSIBuEzMLa1sie0sIKigRYAhsABMNIIQ9eRJqNiJffA94ZHQsXHx-MipqDg9KKGN+M167CGACJGxGFiUqpE54nrMAXwF5wX4RMSQJFTUNBCzhHPzCnWKQxW7e7EkAWwg3OStsFGiAcgAzHUfpxaKSgwA6e0dnK4fmACGgABZsBAcaYCSqNKA5PDRL7HYB-BxOHJAi6SMAVZQaOi0FH6Eg-VIQdL4tAcaECIA)

Comment: oki thanks all  for help, i edit my answer with the approach i retain. :)

Answer (score -1):

Related to the awnser of @captain-yossarian
i retain this approached where is work fine.
But without wrap class where am not fan.

So i return juste a `new ()=>T` without abstract flag ( Type Guard!)

```
export abstract class FooAbstract{
    static registers: typeof FooAbstract[] = [];
   // adding abstract, and than  return wihout abstract 
    static create<T extends FooAbstract>(constr: abstract new ()=>T) {
        return new (constr as new ()=>T)();
    }
}

export  class A extends FooAbstract {
   name:string;
}

FooAbstract.registers.push(A); // in my case i use decoration, but not matter !

// laters
const test = FooAbstract.registers.map((cls)=> cls.create(cls ))
```